# How to change this SQL query to "SELECT DISTINCT" based on one column?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

So I know that using SQL you can't do a DISTINCT based on one column, but looking at other answers it looks like it's possible to do this using a sub query.  Could anyone help me do this with my SQL query?  I've tried a bunch of different ways and can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

I'm trying to SELECT DISTINCT based on the emplid column.  For example, if there are 2 rows with the same emplid, I only want one of them.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.TenantID, rt.term, t.emplid, t.staff, loc.locationName, tt.comment, l.lengthName
FROM TenantTerm tt
INNER JOIN Tenant t ON t.TenantID = tt.TenantID
INNER JOIN RentTerm rt ON rt.TenantID = t.TenantID
INNER JOIN length l ON l.lengthID = tt.lengthID
INNER JOIN location loc ON loc.locationID = tt.locationID
WHERE tt.assigned='0' AND rt.term>='$currentTerm' ORDER BY t.TenantID"
```

And some sample output data:

```
["TenantID"] => string(3) "535" 
["term"]=> string(4) "2137" 
["emplid"]=> string(7) "1855280" 
["staff"]=> string(1) "0" 
["locationName"]=> string(12) "BuildingOne" 
["comment"]=> string(0) "" 
["lengthName"]=> string(13) "Academic Year"
```

Note: Edited to increase clarity and to include sample data.

Comment: What do you want your output to look like? Could you please post some sample data? If you just want DISTINCT values for one column, what value do you want to display for this one column when there are multiple rows?

Comment: Mysql let you use `GROUP BY ` without aggregate function, so `SELECT .... WHERE .... GROUP BY t.emplid ORDER BY ....` may give what you want (check docs about what to expect in resultset , http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html )

Comment: @JosephB I edited my question, does that make it more clear?

Comment: A little better. If you want to select the most recent of duplicate rows, is there a date column which can be used?

Comment: @JosephB There is not.  I'm really sorry my question has so many holes.  Just forget the 'most recent' aspect of it (unless it's necessary), if you could help me with a query that selects only one of the rows based on the emplid like I previously described that would be great.  I've been giving it a go but not finding much success.

Comment: Which table has emplid?

Comment: Ok, let's say you have 2 different `TenantID`'s for a given `emplid`, say 535 and 536 for emplid=1855280. Which one do you want to list? If it is being determined using a column (id / date), please tell us which column. Please consider modifying the query to select that column as well. You yourself might come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking doesn't really make sense, the `DISTINCT` applies to all columns in the `SELECT`.. so if you want just unique `emplid` values returned, what do you expect in the other columns?

If these are consistent already you wouldn't be asking this question, and if you don't care about them, why are you returning them?

The simple answer is:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT t.emplid
    FROM TenantTerm tt
    JOIN Tenant t 
      ON t.TenantID = tt.TenantID
    JOIN RentTerm rt 
      ON rt.TenantID = t.TenantID
    JOIN length l 
      ON l.lengthID = tt.lengthID
    JOIN location loc 
      ON loc.locationID = tt.locationID
   WHERE tt.assigned='0' 
     AND rt.term>='$currentTerm'
ORDER BY t.TenantID
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you are exactly correct in that I want unique emplid values, but only unique emplid values.  If I have multiple rows with the same emplid, I only want the most recent of those rows; however, I still need the other fields as well.

I edited my answer to include some sample data, does that help explain what I'm going for?

Comment: @user2421349 `If I have multiple rows with the same emplid, I only want the most recent of those rows`. How do you determine the most recent row? What is the name of the date column and which table has the date column?

Comment: @user2421349 It is still unclear.. most recent rows of what? I count 5 tables there!